# How to return my own custom MySqlResult class where MySqlResult extends mysqli_result?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, extends

I want to create my own class that extends `mysqli_result`.

How can I do so?

**Example**

```
//my own custom statement class
class MySqlStatement extends \mysqli_stmt
{

    function prepare($sql)
    {
        return parent::prepare($sql);
    }

    function get_result()
    {
        //returns mysqli_result
        return parent::get_result();

        //but I want it to return a custom MySqlResult
    }
}
```

In the above I want to create my own class called `MySqlResult`.  But how do I initialize it?

So far I have

```
class MySqlResult extends \mysqli_result
{
}
```

and I can't think of any way to do it.

Comment: You can use `Traits` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: Traits ... How?

Comment: You can't extend a function?

Comment: You could probably hack together something with: http://php.net/override_function

Comment: @Farkie.. maybe but hey found a similar question with a different technique